# Postgres query to select all records that have at least one matching array value from another array

Tags: postgresql, array

Rough table structure:

```
id                      uuid
fields                  jsonb
created_at              timestamptz
related_content_ids     _uuid
updated_at              timestamptz
```

I'm trying to write a query that will find all records in this table that have at least one value from a specified array in the `related_content_ids` column.

Something like this works for matching all values in the array, but I just need at least one to match:

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE related_content_ids @> '{fbaa1235-1069-496f-9a54-e91e13aadae8,65a109eb-ee4b-4a23-9f91-6980b5bb9340}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"At least one match" can be done using the "overlaps" operator `&&`

```
select *
from content
where related_content_ids && '{fbaa1235-1069-496f-9a54-e91e13aadae8,65a109eb-ee4b-4a23-9f91-6980b5bb9340}'
```